# Text Vertical Scale different from Chrome to FF/IE

Tags: fonts, css, browser

I have simple navigation with Font `Lato` and `font-size:12` but it's showing up different in both browsers, why is this? The size of the box is not that different, but it's the apparel.

I have included the image of demonstration (it's only 2 pixel off) but you can see the text vertical scale is definitely different.

[image: preview of error]

```
.navigation > a {
  padding: 0 1em 0.244em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding: 22px 20px 15px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}
```

body

```
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #787E87;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.618;
    font-family: Lato, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's likely due to the prefixed properties at the bottom of the second CSS section but without a live demo we can't be sure. This is also not a question for GD as it has nothing to do with design

Comment: Probably the answer is in the inspector values (which may not be the actual computed value): pixels can be thought of as integer-based bins (and screens as a grid of bins). Fractions of a pixel must be rounded. Math libraries will vary but I expect <.5 rounds down. Fractional px values are probably due to using ems